# Achieve a basic fuzzy search with no Gem SQLite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a basic add-edit-delete application with records and a search function. So far I can search by attribute ':title' and would like to search by ':price' but really can't figure out how to achieve this without a gem. So a fuzzy search with two searchable attributes.

I feel as though it's really simple...

Here is the controller code for search:

```
  def search
    @products = Product.fuzzy_search(params[:search_string])
    if @products.empty?
     @products = Product.all.order :title
    end
   render :action => "index"
  end
```

(apologies for the bad indentation. Here's [the full controller](https://github.com/Koxzi95/smt-books/blob/master/app/controllers/products_controller.rb) and the [model implementing `fuzzy_search`](https://github.com/Koxzi95/smt-books/blob/master/app/models/product.rb).

Comment: You've defined the `fuzzy_search` function yourself - why not just change it? And how is the controller more relevant than the model implementing it?

Comment: I completely forgot that the model is where the code was :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been more helpful for you to put in the code for the fuzzy_search method itself:

```
  def self.fuzzy_search(search_string)
        search_string = "%" + search_string + "%"
        self.where("title LIKE ?", search_string)
  end
```

Unless I am misunderstanding you, why could you not just do this:

```
  def self.fuzzy_search(search_string)
        search_string = "%" + search_string + "%"
        self.where("title LIKE ? or price LIKE ?", search_string, search_string)
  end
```

Comment: That seems to easy. I think -know- I was overthinking it.